# How to define output layer shape of DQN model in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

i am trying to learn DQN agent to play Tic Tac Toe using Keras. Issue is that my output has different shape than I expected.

Details: 
Input shape : `(BOARD_SIZE ^ 2) * 3` --> It is one hot encoded game board
Output shape: I expect that output will be list with size of `(BOARD_SIZE^2)` because it should number of available actions

Problem: 
Output has shape Size of input layer `[(BOARD_SIZE ^ 2) *3] * Number of actions (BOARD_SIZE^2)`

I tried to look for solutions but Keras documentation is quite poor. Plz help

THIS IS MY MODEL

```
    def create_model(self, game: GameController) -> Sequential:
    input_size = (game.shape ** 2) * 3

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(input_size, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(int(input_size / 2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(int(input_size / 2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense((game.shape ** 2), activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=Adam(self.alpha))

    return model
```

THIS IS HOW I AM TRYING TO GET OUTPUT

```
q_values = self.model.predict(processed_input)
```

THIS IS BOAD PREPROCESSING (ONE HOT ENCODING)

```
def preprocess_input(self, game: GameController) -> list:
    encoded_x = copy.deepcopy(game.board)
    encoded_o = copy.deepcopy(game.board)
    encoded_blank = copy.deepcopy(game.board)

    for row in range(game.shape):
        for col in range(game.shape):
            if encoded_x[row][col] == 'X':
                encoded_x[row][col] = 1
            else:
                encoded_x[row][col] = 0

            if encoded_o[row][col] == 'O':
                encoded_o[row][col] = 1
            else:
                encoded_o[row][col] = 0

            if encoded_blank[row][col] == '-':
                encoded_blank[row][col] = 1
            else:
                encoded_blank[row][col] = 0

    chained_x = list(chain.from_iterable(encoded_x))
    chained_o = list(chain.from_iterable(encoded_o))
    chained_blank = list(chain.from_iterable(encoded_blank))

    string_board = list(chain(chained_x, chained_o, chained_blank))
    board_to_int = [int(element) for element in string_board]

    return board_to_int
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after few tries i find out that my input has been transposed, so I set input_dim to ((BOARD_SIZE^2)*3) and reshaping input_board to (1, (BOARD_SIZE^2)*3) fixed issue. Hope it will helps others in the future :)